# DATEDIFF should return 1 being the first month of contract

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say i have a date and I have the following Get Date by the way is the sql in built function I just showed it in my data what it could be.

```
select * from contract c
  inner join payment p 
  on c.contract = p.contract
  where DATEDIFF(MONTH, c.startDate, getdate())
  <> 1
```

The above works fine if the months are not the same so what i did to kinda fix this was this.

```
select * from contract c
   inner join payment on p.contract= c.contract
   where DATEDIFF(MONTH, c.startDate, getdate())
   <> 1
   and (DATEDIFF(MONTH, c.startDate, getdate())
   <> 0 and DATEDIFF(year, c.startDate, 
   getdate() <> 0)
```

But if you notice I enclose the year and month check in parentheses but will that work So am wanting for it to only take the and into account when the year and month are both 0.

So If I had for example

| Date | GetDate | Months | Should be |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05/11/2022 | 05/11/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 05/12/2022 | 05/11/2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 05/13/2022 | 05/11/2022 | 2 | 2 |
| 05/11/2023 | 05/11/2022 | 12 | 12 |

Comment: This logic makes no sense to me - you want `datediff(month` between `05/11/2022` and `05/11/2022` to be 1? And the `datediff(month` between `05/11/2022` and `05/12/2022` to be 1? And the `datediff(month` between `05/11/2022` and `05/13/2022` to be 2?

Comment: Maybe you actually want `where c.startDate <= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, getdate())`?

Answer (score 2):

Simply change your condition to exclude both 0 and 1 and also negative values:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    contract c
    INNER JOIN payment p
        ON c.contract = p.contract
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, c.startDate, GETDATE()) > 1
```

If you need to consider negative values as well, you can write

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    contract c
    INNER JOIN payment p
        ON c.contract = p.contract
WHERE NOT DATEDIFF(MONTH, c.startDate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN - 1 AND 1
```

or

```sql
...
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(MONTH, c.startDate, GETDATE())) > 1
```

---

If you want to return the difference in months as specified, you can write

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, c.startDate, getdate()) = 0
        THEN 1
        ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH, c.startDate, getdate())
    END AS Months
...
```

But I do not see the point of this, since it is logically wrong. It would make more sense to count all the months involved including the starting month and the end month with `DATEDIFF(MONTH, c.startDate, getdate()) + 1`. So that JAN to JAN would be 1, JAN to FEB would be 2, etc.